# Can't receive mysqli record with password verify

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I just started working with php and I'm not really good at it.I need to verify my user's password and username after they passed that I want to start an session with that users user_id. But everytime I try to echo the user_id I just get nothing back. hope someone can help me with this. is my code:

```
<?php
 require_once "config.php";
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 if (strlen($username) > 0 && strlen($hash) > 0){
  $query = "SELECT user_id FROM keep_user WHERE username =    '$username' AND password = '$hash'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn , $query);
  if($conn->query($query) == TRUE){
     if(password_verify($password, $hash)){
         session_start();
         $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
         echo $user_id;
         echo "succes";
     }else{
         echo "error-1".$conn->error;
     } 
   }else{
        echo "error-2".$conn->error;
        exit;
   }
 }else{
     echo "error".$conn->error;
     exit;
 }
?>
```

It does echo success so I am guessing that part is good but why can't retrieve user_id?

Comment: Is the user_id already in your result array?

Comment: I can see your site supports the Universal Super Password standard: `' OR 1=1-- `. Cool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not with `password_verify` function . Problem is with `mysqli_query` because you execute your query two times

```
 $result = mysqli_query($conn , $query);// first time
  if($conn->query($query) == TRUE){// second time
```

Just comment or remove `$result = mysqli_query($conn , $query);// first time`

To get `user id` form query you need to fetch it as

```
if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ;
    $user_id=$row["user_id"];
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

}
```

And `session_start();` at the top of your page.

You script is open for  sql injection Read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to prevent it

Comment: Dayum, 10 sec to fast :D

Comment: did what you said , still only receive succes